# What is alternative of "DATASET" as connection type in SSRS 2008-r2?

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

I have one older project that is implemented SSRS 2005. We have written all C# code for creating RDL file, Creating DataSource and Report on Report Server. When we are creating DataSoruce definition then we use to set Extension as "DATASET" and all code are working fine, This application is already in Production from last 7 years and able to generate SSRS reports smoothly.

Now in production, SSRS 2005 is going to upgrade with SSRS 2008, So for that we have to change our current implementation. In SSRS 2008 there is no option as "DATASET" in Connection Type(Data Source Type) dropdown while creating a shared Data Source. So I use "SQL" as a connection type but not able to render report in the Report Viewer. 
Please Help !!

Showing error: SSRS 2008 Error.PNG
SSRS 2005 Datasource Connection Option: [image]
SSRS 2008[image] Datasource Connection Option: [image]

Answer (score 0):

I've never actually seen someone use a shared dataset. Anyway, If I recall correctly dataset in sql 2005 was the results of a query, however Microsoft has put the information regarding this particular data source type in the dark recesses of tech net behind a sign that says beware the leopard. Jokes aside an hour of googling and browsing technet, and I couldn't even find a reference to this connection type.

If memory servers you'll find the data definition in the actual connection itself, by going to the data source properties. Once you have the definition, you can either use it to update the data set in the report, or you can create a view in the db that matches the definition, and then point the dataset in the report at the view. Good luck.